# delphi (XE7) and mingw gcc compatibility (switch statement with 5 and more cases)

Tags: delphi, gcc, dll

I am trying to use C code in Delphi. I am facing issue while compiling and including *.o file built by gcc. Concrete example:
C source file "simple.c" code:

```
void foo343(){};
void __cdecl foo5 ();

void __cdecl foo5 ()
{
int i =4;
  switch (i){
   case 0:
   break;
   case 1:
   break;
   case 2:
   break;
   case 3:
   break;
   case 4:
   break;
   default:
   break;
  }
}
```

Compiled by following command:

```
gcc  -fno-leading-underscore  -c simple.c
```

This will produce simple.o file, which will be used in following delphi project:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils;

{$L simple.o}
procedure foo5 (); cdecl; external ;

begin

  try
    foo5;   {<-- here the exception will occur)
    Writeln('hello world~~~!!!');
    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);

  end;
    readln;
end.
```

Problem is, that this simple program doesn't work (fail on call of foo5). I have made another trial, I have produced "dll" from object file simple.o by command (-fno-leading-underscore must be excluded this time) :

```
gcc -g -c simple.c
gcc -g -shared -o simple.dll simple.o
```

Slightly change the delphi code:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils;

//{$L simple.o}
procedure foo5 (); cdecl; external 'simple.dll' ;

begin

  try
    foo5;    {this time no fail}
    Writeln('hello world~~~!!!');
    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);

  end;
    readln;
end.
```

Failure with "o" is on the instruction

```
70A81593 8B00             mov eax,[eax]
```

Where eax conatins value 10, so really memory with address 10 cannot be read.
I have found the difference. When I decompiled "o" file and "dll" by objdump -S, I have found that dll has before mov instruction

```
70A8158E 056440A870       add eax,$70a84064
```

while "o" has

```
00419ECE 0500000000       add eax,$00000000
```

This difference causes that eax while using dll contains reasonable value, but eax while using "o" contains wrong value

In my project would like to use o files instead of dll. Do you know why gcc do different compiled instruction for o and for dll? I there a way to force gcc to make same instructions for o files?

Comment: I've never had much luck with statically linked objects compiled by mingw. I use bcc32 for 32 bit builds and cl for 64 bit builds.

Comment: thanks for hint bcc32 works for all cases. My intention is to start using gcc in our project. I have feeling that gcc has most optimized code for performance, and that's the reason why I want to try gcc.

Comment: BTW, if someone will want to try above code, please don't skip foo343 from the simple.c file. From uknown reason delphi doesn't accept functions from "o" files with address 0000000. So I put empty function to C file to move function foo5 to higher address.

Comment: As I said mingw has never yielded success for me. Try cl if you want more efficient code than bcc32.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your hints. I have succeeded also with the gcc, the problem with switch statement was solved by -O2 switch. I don't know the explanation now, may be investigate later.. I am interested in "cl" compiler. I would like to use it as gcc with "no-leading-underscore" switch, but seems there is nothing like that. What's your experience? Martin

Comment: I add the underscore in Pascal.